# Accessing an HTML element within a <ul> with Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium

I'm trying to access an HTML element using Selenium (Java) but am currently having trouble. The element is located within this structure:

```
    <nav>
       <ul class="...menu"> id="...menu">
          <li id="Ignore..."> </li>
          <li id="Test tab">
             <a href="/.../..." title="Tab">Tab</a>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </nav>
```

I need to access and click `"Tab"` which appears as a button. What is the best method to access this button? I have tried `.findElement(By.name("..."));` and similar without success. Once `"Tab"` has been selected I then plan to call `.click()`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with this solution

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Tab']")).click();
```